# How to set different margin (not mirroring) for even and odd pages?

Tags: margins

I'm a beginner in Latex and I want to create a file with different margins on even and odd pages, like in the picture.
[image]
How can I do it?

Comment: you can not do that as paragraphs are broken in to lines before page breaking, so you can have different margins on odd and even pages but the width of the text block must be the same

Comment: you can have pages with margins as you show but you would have to have manual `\clearpage` page breaks as any automatic page break would have the lines at the top of the page still using the line width from the previous page

Comment: You can do it with the flowfram package, but as @DavidCarlisle mentioned, paragraphs will not break nicely at page boundaries.  You can however manualy break the paragraphs and make it look like one paragraph.

Answer (score 3):

You have to have manual page breaking as if a paragraph breaks over a page the line length for the part carried over to the next page would be wrong.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\newcommand\evenpage{%
  \clearpage
  \setlength\oddsidemargin{\dimexpr2cm-1in}%
  \setlength\textwidth{\dimexpr\paperwidth-4cm}%
  \setlength\columnwidth{\textwidth}%
  \setlength\linewidth{\columnwidth}%
  \setlength\hsize{\linewidth}%
  \clearpage}

\newcommand\oddpage{%
  \clearpage
  \setlength\oddsidemargin{\dimexpr2cm-1in}%
  \setlength\textwidth{\dimexpr\paperwidth-7.8cm}%
  \setlength\columnwidth{\textwidth}%
  \setlength\linewidth{\columnwidth}%
  \setlength\hsize{\linewidth}%
  \clearpage}


\begin{document}

\evenpage

\section{Hmmm}
XXX\dotfill XXX

XXX\dotfill XXX

\lipsum


\oddpage

\section{Hmmm}
XXX\dotfill XXX

XXX\dotfill XXX

\lipsum[1-5]

XXX\dotfill XXX


\evenpage

\section{Hmmm}
XXX\dotfill XXX

XXX\dotfill XXX

\lipsum


\oddpage

\section{Hmmm}
XXX\dotfill XXX

XXX\dotfill XXX

\lipsum[1-5]

XXX\dotfill XXX



\end{document}
```

Comment: ive used evenpage for odd numbers and oddpage for even as my pdf viwer side by side doesn't let you start page 1 on the right, perhaps I should have added a page 0,

Answer (score 2):

Here is a flowfram solution.  The starred version draws lines around the flowframes.  Note the use of `\nopar` to manually break the paragraphs.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{flowfram}

\usepackage{lipsum}% random text

\newflowframe*[odd]{\textwidth}{\textheight}{0pt}{0pt}

\newflowframe*[even]{\dimexpr \textwidth-3.8cm}%
  {\dimexpr \textheight-1cm}{0pt}{1cm}
  
\newcommand{\nopar}{{\parfillskip=0pt\par}\pagebreak\noindent}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-8]

Morbi luctus, wisi viverra faucibus pretium, nibh est placerat odio, nec commodo wisi enim eget quam. Quisque
libero justo, consectetuer a, feugiat vitae, porttitor eu, libero. Suspendisse sed mauris vitae elit sollicitudin
malesuada. Maecenas ultricies eros sit amet ante. Ut venenatis velit. Maecenas sed mi eget dui varius euismod.
Phasellus aliquet volutpat odio. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia
Curae; Pellentesque sit amet pede ac sem eleifend consectetuer. Nullam elementum, urna vel imperdiet sodales,
elit ipsum pharetra ligula, ac pretium ante justo a nulla. Curabitur tristique arcu eu metus. Vestibulum lectus.
Proin mauris. Proin eu nunc eu urna hendrerit faucibus. Aliquam auctor, pede consequat laoreet varius, eros tellus
\nopar
scelerisque quam, pellentesque hendrerit ipsum dolor sed augue. Nulla nec lacus.

\lipsum[10-16]

Curabitur tellus magna, porttitor a, commodo a, commodo in, tortor. Donec interdum.
Praesent scelerisque. Maecenas posuere sodales odio. Vivamus metus lacus, varius
quis, imperdiet quis, rhoncus a, turpis. Etiam ligula arcu, elementum a, venenatis quis,
sollicitudin sed, metus. Donec nunc pede, tincidunt in, venenatis vitae, faucibus vel, nibh.
\nopar
Pellentesque wisi. Nullam malesuada. Morbi ut tellus ut pede tincidunt porta. Lorem
ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Etiam congue neque id dolor.

\lipsum[18-20]
\end{document}
```